# Does $x^2=83\pmod{101}$ have solutions? without calculating them

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, systems-of-equations, quadratics, chinese-remainder-theorem

Does $x^2=83\pmod{101}$ have solutions? without calculating them.
I'm not sure how to tackle this without solving, I tried using chinese remainder and quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: Best if you show us how your calculations went. Quadratic reciprocity should do the trick, so maybe where can see where you got stuck.

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use the supplements to quadratic reciprocity? If yes, the problem is easily solved by noting that $83 \equiv -18 \equiv -1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3^2 \mod 101$. $-1$ is a square modulo $101$ and $2$ isn't, so $83$ is not a square modulo $101$.